# Find $n$ such that $365 \left(1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n - n\frac{364^{n-1}}{365^n} \right) > 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, birthday

I need to find $n$ such that $365 \left(1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n - n\frac{364^{n-1}}{365^n} \right) > 1$. The answer is $n \ge 28$. Expanding the equation out, rearranging it, taking logarithm, I get 
$$\log(364) > \log(365) + n\log(364/365) + \log(n) +(n-1)\log(364/365).$$

I don't know what to do next. I would appreciate if you give me some hint.

Comment: Since $n$ appears both inside and outside the transcendental function $\log$, you shouldn't be able to solve for the equality exactly without the use of special functions. On the other hand, you can observe that the right hand side is an increasing function.

Comment: Do you mean $n \le 28?$  In the original question the left side is decreasing with $n$.  It is certainly true for $n=0,1$

Comment: I double check the solution, and $n \ge 28$. This question comes from Q.18, p. 239, Feller Volume 1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the same inequality as you do.  We have $$
365 \left(1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n - n\frac{364^{n-1}}{365^n} \right) > 1\\
364> \frac{364^n}{365^{n-1}}+n\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n-1}\\
364>(364+n)\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^{n-1}\\
\log364>\log(364+n)+(n-1)\log\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)\\
(n-1)\log\left(\frac{365}{364}\right)>\log\left(\frac{364+n}{364}\right)\\
(n-1)\log\left(1+\frac1{364}\right)>\log\left(1+\frac n{364}\right)
$$
I haven't carried it past this point.  I would try applying the inequalities $$x-\frac{x^2}{2}<\log(1+x)<x,\ |x|<1$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the inequality writing $a=364$, $$(a+1)\left(1-\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)^n-n\left(\frac{a^{n-1}}{(a+1)^n}\right)\right)>1.$$
A bit of rearranging leads to
$$\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)^{n-1}>1+\frac{n}{a}.$$
Take the natural log of both sides to get
$$ (n-1)\ln \left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right) > \ln\left(1+\frac{n}{a}\right).$$
The simplest way to go from here is to use the inequality $\ln(1+x)\ge \frac{2x}{2+x}$ for all $x \ge 0$. As $\frac{n}{a}$ is small it is reasonably accurate. Substituting in that inequality and rearranging eventually yields
$$ n^2+b\,n-2a>0 $$
where $$b=2a-1-\frac{2}{\ln\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)}.$$
Thus 
$$ n>-b+\sqrt{b^2+2a}\approx 27.9998. $$

However, this is a necessary condition but possibly not sufficient. To find the exact value of $n$ I think you would require a numerical method. You can getter a slightly better bound by instead starting from
$$\left(\frac{a+1}{a}\right)^{n-2}>1+\frac{n-1}{a+1}.$$
Using the same log inequality and working it through it is found that $n$ has to be slightly larger than $28$.

This is confirmed when checking the original problem. It does not hold for $n=28$, but does hold for $n=29$. So if $n$ is an integer one requires $n\ge 29$ not $n\ge 28$.

Perhaps you could look into the log inequality used to see if you could put a bound on the error induced by using it, or find a better inequality, so that you have a better idea of the bound on $n$.